# Sentence for saying that something is further ahead

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am looking for a sentence that tells someone that something is further ahead.

For example: if I want to tell a reader (currently reading page 20) about a topic that is further ahead (say on page 50) without mentioning the page, how will the sentence be?

Would it be something like: *The topic is further ahead.*

Also, please mention different ways of saying this. I want to learn different ways this sentence can be structured, for the sake of variety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inform the reader that more information will be coming later on you could use

> This/[X] will be covered/discussed later
>
> This/[X] will be covered/discussed in a later chapter
>
> This/[X] will be covered/discussed in more detail/depth later on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your sentence is much better in this context, but I would still like to ask whether "(Something) is further ahead" is correct grammatically and whether it makes sense in some other context, say, a sign board that informs about a place further forward in space and tells to keep moving. How would such a sentence be?

Comment: @Zaeem Certainly. *The truck stop is further ahead*. Although road signs would usually state a distance. Can also be used figuratively: *Salvation is further ahead*

Comment: In academic writing, it is **very** common to say that a topic will be "addressed below," "discussed below," etc. – particularly if the reference is to a point within a few pages farther along in the text. "Later" and especially "later on" would seem too colloquial in such a context; "in a later chapter" is OK, but "in Chapter 3" (or whatever) would be much better.